# Mail go to spam using PHP

Tags: php, smtp

I want to send mail to inbox using smtp mail method using PHP.Now mail go to spam instead of inbox,i am using smtp mail method.I had set the hostname,username and password.Included the  class.phpmailer.Mail body contain HTML content.

```
<?php

 define("SMTP_HOST", "mail.test.com"); //Hostname of the mail server
 define("SMTP_PORT", "25"); //Port of the SMTP like to be 25, 80, 465 or 587
  define("SMTP_UNAME", "tttt"); 
 //Username for SMTP authentication any valid   email created in your domain
 define("SMTP_PWORD", "tttt"); //Password for SMTP authentication
?>


Mail Code

//smtp mail
$mail   = new PHPMailer;
$mail->Host = SMTP_HOST; 
$mail->Port = SMTP_PORT; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = SMTP_UNAME; 
$mail->Password = SMTP_PWORD; 
$mail->AddReplyTo("test@test.com", "test"); 
$mail->SetFrom("test@test.com", "test.com"); 
$mail->Subject = $subject; 
$mail->AddAddress($to, '');
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$send = $mail->Send(); 
$mail->ClearAddresses();

 //smtp mail
```

Anybody help me?

Comment: question should be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Use sender email your domain email.Like your domain name is example.com use a email like info@example.com if you use like this types email,there is a better possibility to send email in inbox.